# PHP Exported excel file lost editing data

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I have exported an excel file (.xls) with formula, (using `application/vnd.ms-excel`)

when export, the window show up an option to open with or save file

the case is

when I choose to save file and
after made some editing to that file, if I open the file that file again in the same day the editing/additional data still there,
but after that day the additional/editing data is gone

anyone know why this thing happen and how to fix this?

Comment: Please add code. How are you expecting. What window are you talking about. It's very hard to understand the flow of what you are trying to do.

Comment: no problem with the code to create the files, no error, and created as expected...the problem is after the file is saved into a place and changes is made to the excel file, for the same day of created, the changed data is still there, another day file is open and the changed is gone just like first time created

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. Show us the code, show us the issue.